# Sending messages and roadside to roadside (R2R) communication in Veins

Tags: veins

I'm new in Omnet Veins. I try to create my own application. So first of all, I have done this in the existing TraciDemo11p files (I have just kept the files name and modify the code). 
In the first step, I want to make all nodes sending a HelloMsg (a new packet that I have created .msg .h and .cc).

To well understand how messages are exchanged between nodes, I launched the simulation and all is well, but I cannot realize if the messages are received by nodes or not.

This is a screenshot of what I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqiM.png)

I followed the transmission of the message between the application, mac and phy layers. I can see that the message is successfully transmitted by node[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vqiM.png) for example. But does the message on node[0] "packet was not detected by the card. power was under sensitivity threshold" mean that the packet was not received by node[0]?. If it is the case, how can I fix that? Also, I cannot find the source file of this message (apparently, in PhyLayer80211p.cc or BasehyLayer.cc but I cannot find it).

In the second step, I want to use two RSUs. Nodes broadcast a helloMessage and then each RSU will repeat the received signal. To clarify more, this exactly what I have:
First of all. I add another RSU to the veins example as follows:

```
##########################################################
#                       RSU SETTINGS                     #
#                                                        #
#                                                        #
##########################################################
*.rsu[0].mobility.x = 6490
*.rsu[0].mobility.y = 1000
*.rsu[0].mobility.z = 3

*.rsu[1].mobility.x = 7491
*.rsu[1].mobility.y = 1000
*.rsu[1].mobility.z = 3

*.rsu[*].applType = "TraCIDemoRSU11p"
*.rsu[*].appl.headerLength = 80 bit
*.rsu[*].appl.sendBeacons = false
*.rsu[*].appl.dataOnSch = false
*.rsu[*].appl.beaconInterval = 1s
*.rsu[*].appl.beaconUserPriority = 7
*.rsu[*].appl.dataUserPriority = 5
```

Also, I made two maxInterferenceDistance, one of the nodes and the other for the RSUs:

```
##########################################################
#            11p specific parameters                     #
#                                                        #
#                    NIC-Settings                        #
##########################################################
*.connectionManager.sendDirect = true
*.connectionManager.maxInterfDist = 1000m  #2600m
*.connectionManager.drawMaxIntfDist = false #false
*.connectionManager.maxInterfDistNodes = 300m
*.connectionManager.drawMaxIntfDistNodes = false

*.**.nic.mac1609_4.useServiceChannel = false

*.**.nic.mac1609_4.txPower = 20mW
*.**.nic.mac1609_4.bitrate = 6Mbps
*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm

*.**.nic.phy80211p.useThermalNoise = true
*.**.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm

*.**.nic.phy80211p.decider = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.analogueModels = xmldoc("config.xml")
*.**.nic.phy80211p.usePropagationDelay = true

*.**.nic.phy80211p.antenna = xmldoc("antenna.xml", "/root/Antenna[@id='monopole']")
```

To make the transmission range of RSU different on that of nodes, I made this change in the isInRange function of the baseConnectionMannager:

```
bool BaseConnectionManager::isInRange(BaseConnectionManager::NicEntries::mapped_type pFromNic, BaseConnectionManager::NicEntries::mapped_type pToNic)
{
    double dDistance = 0.0;

    if ((pFromNic->hostId == 7) || (pFromNic->hostId == 8)) {
        EV<<"RSU In range from: "<<pFromNic->getName()<<" "<<pFromNic->hostId<<" to: "<<pToNic->getName()<<" "<<pToNic->hostId<<"\n";
    if(useTorus) {
        dDistance = sqrTorusDist(pFromNic->pos, pToNic->pos, *playgroundSize);
    } else {
        dDistance = pFromNic->pos.sqrdist(pToNic->pos);
    }
    return (dDistance <= maxDistSquared);
    } else {
        if(useTorus) {
                dDistance = sqrTorusDist(pFromNic->pos, pToNic->pos, *playgroundSize);
            } else {
                dDistance = pFromNic->pos.sqrdist(pToNic->pos);
            }
            return (dDistance <= maxDistSquaredNodes);
    }
}
```

Where node IDs 7 and 8 are the RSUs in the scenario I run.

In addition, I have the TraciDemo11p (for nodes) and TraciDemoRSU11p (for RSUs) modified as follow:
- In the TraciDemo11p, nodes when enter the network broadcast a Hello message to all their neighbors. The code is:

```
void TraCIDemo11p::initialize(int stage) {

    BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
    if (stage == 0) {
        HelloMsg *msg = createMsg();
        SendHello(msg);
    }
}

HelloMsg* TraCIDemo11p::createMsg() {
    int source_id = myId;
    double t0 = 0;
    int port = 0;

    char msgName[20];
    sprintf(msgName, "send Hello from %d at %f from gate %d",source_id, t0, port);

    HelloMsg* msg = new HelloMsg(msgName);
    populateWSM(msg);
    return msg;
}

void TraCIDemo11p::SendHello(HelloMsg* msg) {
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
    msg->setSource_id(myId);
    cMessage* mm = dynamic_cast<cMessage*>(msg);
    scheduleAt(simTime() + 10 + uniform(0.01, 0.02), mm);
}

void TraCIDemo11p::handleSelfMsg(cMessage* msg) {

    if (dynamic_cast<HelloMsg*>(msg)) {
        HelloMsg* recv = dynamic_cast<HelloMsg*>(msg);
        ASSERT(recv);
        int sender = recv->getSource_id();
        if (sender == myId) {
            EV <<myId <<" broadcasting Hello Message \n";
            recv->setT0(SIMTIME_DBL(simTime()));
            sendDown(recv->dup());
        }
    }
    else {
        BaseWaveApplLayer::handleSelfMsg(msg);
    }
}

void TraCIDemo11p::onHelloMsg(HelloMsg* hmsg) {
    if ((hmsg->getSource_id() == 7) || (hmsg->getSource_id() == 8)) {
        EV <<"Node: "<<myId<<" receiving HelloMsg from rsu: "<<hmsg->getSource_id()<<"\n";
    } else {
    EV <<"Node: "<<myId<<" receiving HelloMsg "<<hmsg->getKind()<<" from node: "<<hmsg->getSource_id()<<"\n";
    NBneighbors++;
    neighbors.push_back(hmsg->getSource_id());
    EV <<"Node: "<<myId<<" neighbors list: ";
    list<int>::iterator it = neighbors.begin();
    while (it != neighbors.end()) {
        EV <<*it<<" ";
        it++;
    }
    }
}

void TraCIDemo11p::handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::handlePositionUpdate(obj);
}
```

On the other hand, RSUs just repeat the message they received from nodes. So, I have on the TraciDemoRSU11p:

```
void TraCIDemoRSU11p::onHelloMsg(HelloMsg* hmsg) {

    if ((hmsg->getSource_id() != 7) && (hmsg->getSource_id() != 8))
    {
        EV <<"RSU: "<<myId<<" receiving HelloMsg "<<hmsg->getKind()<<" from node: "<<hmsg->getSource_id()<<" at: "<<SIMTIME_DBL(simTime())<<" \n";
        //HelloMsg *msg = createMsg();
        //SendHello(msg);
        hmsg->setSenderAddress(myId);
        hmsg->setSource_id(myId);
        sendDelayedDown(hmsg->dup(), 2 + uniform(0.01,0.2));
    }
    else {
        EV<<"Successful connection between RSUs \n";
        EV <<"RSU: "<<myId<<" receiving HelloMsg "<<hmsg->getKind()<<" from node: "<<hmsg->getSource_id()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

After the execution of this code, I can see:

- a few numbers of vehicles receiving the hello message from their neighbors.
- also, just a few messages were received by the two RSUs.
- Each RSUs repeats the signal it receives, but there is no communication between the two RSU, which are supposed in the transmission of one another.
- And always I have a lot of this message "packet was not detected by the card. power was under sensitivity threshold" printed on my screen.

Is there any problem in the transmission range or it is a question of interference? Also, I would like to mention that in the analysis there is no packet loss.
Thanks in advance.
Please help.

Comment: Which version of Veins are you using? Have you changed anything else in the tutorial simulation?

Comment: I'm using veins 4.7.1 version under omnet ++ 5.4.1. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: Which configuration of the tutorial simulation are you executing? Are any nodes transmitting other than newly starting cars? If so, you might simply be seeing a transmission from very far away.

Comment: Thanks Christoph Sommer for your response. I use the general configuration.